# Create Apple Distribution p12 cert using OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: ios, windows, ssl, openssl, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to create a valid distribution cert for iOS with openssl. From what I can find I need to merge the following into a p12 file:
development cert,
development cert key,
distribution cert,
distribution cert key

I have tried various ways to combine them
`openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in ios_development.pem -out ios_development.p12`
this command will only allow me to do one key and one pem

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: - Use mac to create an apple distribution certificate and export it to use in windows if required, that's what I could recommend to do it quickly.